# How to transform items of a list into dictionary values

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

I have a list:

```
mylist = [0.2577, 0.2311, 0.6393, 0.159, 0.6135]

dic = {'Bag': None, 'Door': None, 'Duck': None, 'Car': None, 'Girl': None}
```

How do I use a for loop to make the items of mylist become the values of my dic, respectively. (It needs to go in order)

```
 # The output should be:

{'Bag': 0.2577, 'Door': 0.2311, 'Duck': 0.6393, 'Car': 0.159, 'Girl': 0.6135}
```

Comment: Why don't you set the values directly?

Comment: I have to do that 30 times with different lists and dictionaries. It would save me a lot of time by having a robust code doing it for me.

Answer (score 5):

For new versions of Python, you can create a new dictionary with [`dict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-dict) + [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
dict(zip(dic, mylist))
# {'Bag': 0.2577, 'Door': 0.2311, 'Duck': 0.6393, 'Car': 0.159, 'Girl': 0.6135}
```

Or update the dictionary in place:

```
for k, v in zip(dic, mylist):
    dic[k] = v

print(dic)
# {'Bag': 0.2577, 'Door': 0.2311, 'Duck': 0.6393, 'Car': 0.159, 'Girl': 0.6135}
```

But this assumes ordered dictionaries for **Python3.6+**. If you are using lower versions which have *unordered* dictionaries, you can use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) to remember the order in which keys are inserted.

**OrderedDict Example:**

```
from collections import OrderedDict

mylist = [0.2577, 0.2311, 0.6393, 0.159, 0.6135]

items = ['Bag', 'Door', 'Duck', 'Car', 'Girl']

d = OrderedDict(zip(items, mylist))

print(d)
# OrderedDict([('Bag', 0.2577), ('Door', 0.2311), ('Duck', 0.6393), ('Car', 0.159), ('Girl', 0.6135)])
```

You can also combine the above examples to only use lists, which are *ordered*:

```
mylist = [0.2577, 0.2311, 0.6393, 0.159, 0.6135]

items = ['Bag', 'Door', 'Duck', 'Car', 'Girl']

d = dict(zip(items, mylist))

print(d)
# {'Bag': 0.2577, 'Door': 0.2311, 'Duck': 0.6393, 'Car': 0.159, 'Girl': 0.6135}
```

and is the most straightforward solution to your problem, since it creates a dictionary directly.

Answer (score 0):

This should probably work:

```
dict(zip(dic.keys(), mylist))
```